# How replace each accented characters with non-accented characters foreach word in array in clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I have a array of words, ['cami**ó**n', 'el**á**stico', '**Á**rbol'] and I want replace accented characters with non-accented characters for each word in array (['cami**o**n', 'el**a**stico', '**A**rbol'])

I'm searching some as this

```
SELECT arrayMap(x -> replaceRegexpAll(x, ['á', 'é', 'í', 'ó', 'ú'], ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']), ['camión', 'elástico', 'Árbol']) AS word
```

And I want this result:

```
['camion', 'elastico', 'arbol']
```

Replacing each characters accents  to withouth accent, but this doesn't work...

Any idea from solve?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[New feature](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/string-replace-functions/#translateutf8string-from-to) add functions `translate(string, from_string, to_string)` and `translateUTF8(string, from_string, to_string)`.

These functions replace characters in the original string according to the mapping of each character in from_string to to_string.

```
SELECT  arrayMap(y ->  translateUTF8(y,'áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ','aeiouAEIOU'), ['camión', 'elástico', 'Árbol']) r

r                            |
-----------------------------+
['camion','elastico','Arbol']|
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT arrayMap(x -> arrayStringConcat(
        arrayMap(y -> if((indexOf(['á', 'é', 'í', 'ó', 'ú'],y) as i) = 0, y, ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'][i] ), extractAll(x,'.'))),
         ['camión', 'elástico', 'Árbol']) r

┌─r─────────────────────────────┐
│ ['camion','elastico','Árbol'] │
└───────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: I'll add uppercase and perfect!!! 

`SELECT arrayMap(x -> arrayStringConcat(
        arrayMap(y -> if((indexOf(['Á','á', 'é', 'í', 'ó', 'ú'],y) as i) = 0, y, ['a','a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'][i] ), extractAll(x,'.'))),
         ['camión', 'elástico', 'Árbol']) r `

Thanks Denny!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better option

```sql
SELECT
    original_string,
    normalizeUTF8NFD(original_string) AS decomposed_string,
    replaceRegexpAll(decomposed_string, '([\\x{0300}-\\x{036F}])', '') AS non_accented_string,
    tokens(non_accented_string) tokens
FROM
(
    SELECT 'Café, façade, naïve, jalapeño' AS original_string
)
```

Breaking it down:
**Normalization to NFD (`normalizeUTF8NFD(original_string) AS decomposed_string`):**

`normalizeUTF8NFD` is a function that converts the original string to the Unicode Normalization Form D (NFD). In NFD, composite characters like accented characters are decomposed into their base characters followed by the accent as a separate character. For example, 'é' in 'Café' would be decomposed into 'e' and an acute accent.

**Removing Accent Marks (`replaceRegexpAll(decomposed_string, '([\\x{0300}-\\x{036F}])', '') AS non_accented_string`):**

`replaceRegexpAll` is used to remove the accent marks. The regular expression '([\x{0300}-\x{036F}])' matches all characters in the Unicode range from U+0300 to U+036F, which includes the diacritical marks used for accents in various languages.
By replacing these characters with an empty string '', all accent marks are removed, leaving only the base characters.

[Output of running the SQL from above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1Mst.png)